# Wordpress cron – event added to queue but not firing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cron, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to hook into the `woocommerce_order_status_changed` action and add a single event to the wp cron to execute immediately (so that the request-response cycle is not blocked):

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'on_new_status', 10, 3);
add_action('send_new_status_custom_hook', 'logic_on_new_status', 10, 2);
function on_new_status($order_id, $from, $to){
  wp_schedule_single_event(time(), 'send_new_status_custom_hook', array($from, $to));
}
function logic_on_new_status($first, $second){
  // code
}
```

The event *is* added to the cron (I can see it using a plugin), but not executed. When I click on "execute" manually, it *is* executed.

What could the problem be?

I am using Wordpress 5.3.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution! The issue was caused by my firewall settings...

They were blocking the loopback which wp-cron requires to function properly.

Installing this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/ showed me
the error message "cURL error 28".

From there, I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you are using cron from Wordpress but some plugins disable or prevent CRON from working.
My recommendation in this case is either you create this schedule through the Server Cron or you install a plugin to reaffirm your schedule

Comment: I've tried to disable several plugins, without effect. Any examples of plugins that are used to "reaffirm the schedule"?

Comment: Hi I had the same problem it was even a little difficult to find ...
And as you will see it doesn't have a current update, but for me it works. Send news

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/

Comment: Thanks for your help, the first plugin helped me discover the issue!

Comment: I thank you for the feedback, so that we will find a viable solution.

Just needing to call ...

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind here is, why do you need to use the cron at all?  If your next function is to be run immediately after another, just run that function at that time.  No need to add to the cron.  Cron is generally used for scheduling things that need to be run on a recurring schedule, not necessarily for running a function one time after another function has run.

Also, check your Wordpress timezone vs. your server timezone.  That trips people up occasionally.

Comment: The function I need to run makes blocking http requests. I was hoping to be able to mitigate the load time for users by using the cron in this way.